# Should'nt there be a colon (':') in the method declaration?

Tags: methods, smalltalk

I see following code from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/New-kinds-of-Numbers.html#New-kinds-of-Numbers):

```
+ val [
    <category: 'math'>
    ^Complex real: (realpart + val real)
        imaginary: (imagpart + val imaginary)
]
- val [
    <category: 'math'>
    ^Complex real: (realpart - val real)
        imaginary: (imagpart - val imaginary)
]
```

These define methods/function of `+` and `-`. I generally find the functions/methods are defined as follows (from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/Moving-money-around.html#Moving-money-around)):

```
spend: amount [
    <category: 'moving money'>
    balance := balance - amount
]
```

Why there is no `:` (colon) after `+` and `-` in code mentioned above?

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three types of messages, unary, binary, and keyword. Only the keyword message has a colon. I suggest that you try out the short, on-line, tutorial at https://amber-lang.net/learn.html.

Comment: You answer is superior to mine, thank you for a simple and consise answer.